# TSQL sp_OACreate does not create an token as response

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, msxml2

I am trying to get data from a webservice in to a Json_table variable so i can process it later.
I try to follow and reproduce the code in tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93q8joTcRpQ and try it with another url (see code below). I expect a response in the result grid but instead the error is raised that there is no object created.

I also reconfigured the sql server as was suggested:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE 
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

The code what i use for getting the data is:

```
declare @token          int
      , @ret            int
      , @url            nvarchar(max)
      , @authheader     nvarchar(64)
      , @contenttype    nvarchar(64)
      , @apikey         nvarchar(32)

declare @json           AS TABLE(Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))

-- URL to webservice
SET @url = 'https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataApi/OData/80477ned/PlaatsEnGemeentenamen'

-- Create new instance to of webrequest
--EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token, OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token, OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open http Connnection', 10 , 1)

-- Open connnection and send request with get method
EXEC @ret  = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', null, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret  = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

-- insert response into JSON tablevariable
INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'ResponseText'

-- grap jsson string from jsontablevariable
select * from @json
```

I really appreciate the help !! Manny thanks

Erik

Comment: Do yourself a favour and avoid `sp_OA` procedures like the plague. They are ancient procedures that are there for legacy reasons, they are not maintained, are insecure, difficult to code against and a nightmare to debug. They also hog server threads waiting for responses. Write a Powershell script (or C# or Python app or something) and use that to import into SQL.

Comment: Hi Charlieface! I understand your comment! The point is that Python/C# or powershell is not part of a database and lineage from source to target is by default supported on database level. For every language outside the database i don't have datalineage. So i am searching for a solution on database level.

Comment: It's not really "supported", it's a complete hack anyway. To quote @DavidBrowne in the linked post, who is an official spokesman for Microsoft: "Not because it's a good idea, but  so that no one else has to figure out how to use the horrid sp_OAxxx stored procedures". It's just not worth it. Use the correct tool for a job, in this case T-SQL is the wrong one